# JSON строка должна состоять из массива объектов, где в каждом объекте должны быть следующие параметры

Tags: json, строки

Внутри параметра modification должна быть JSON строка. JSON должен состоять из массива объектов, где в каждом объекте должны быть следующие параметры:

Параметр    Описание
m           Id модификации тех. карты
a           Количество модификации тех. карты

делаю так:
`'modification' => json_encode(array((object)array('m' =>'3', 'a'=>'1'), (object)array('m' =>'19', 'a'=>'1')))`

Результат:
`modification: "[{"m":"3","a":"1"},{"m":"19","a":"1"}]"`

Но API не принимает такой запрос.

Помогите пожалуйста правильно составить запрос

Comment: мало информации. в первых как Вы это в апи передаете? во вторых вероятно у апи так же есть свои требования к получаемым данным. опишите пожалуйста подробнее хотя бы в том как это и куда попадает. если это get параметры, то они должны быть кодированы соответственно. о кодировании есть тут [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
$modification_option = array(
                    (object)array(
                        'm' => 9,
                        'a' => 1
                    ),
                    (object)array(
                        'm' => 19,
                        'a' => 1
                    )
                );

$modification = json_encode($modification_option);
```

Такая запись решила проблему

Comment: Зачем массивы внутри переводить в объекты, если это делает все функция json_encode, абсолютно лишняя вещь